# Manipulate a checkbox to have CSS rotate when unchecked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, rotation, unchecked

I made a mobile navigation with a `checkbox` to have a dropdown menu. When the `checkbox` is checked *(the nav is 'open')*, it rotates 180deg, so the arrow faces upwards. I would like to have the same effect backwards when I click on it.
The problem is that I do not know how to reach a state like `checkbox:unchecked` *(which doesn't make sense, because a checkbox is unchecked by default else you do not define checked in html)* or should I use something like `:after`?

I tried something like this but did not work ( I guess I am not using right syntax)

```
     #menu-toggle:checked~label i  {    /*Rotates when checked*/
     
         transform: rotate(180deg);
         transition: all ease-in-out .3s
      }

     #menu-toggle:checked:after~label i  {  /*My trial to reach the same reverse rotation when unchecked*/
         transform: rotate(-180deg);
         transition: all ease-in-out .3s
      }
```

1.Arrow in default state:

[image]

2. Arrow facing up when checked:

[image]

Only CSS, no JS or jQuery now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple, by default a `transition` on an element makes sure that any kind of change goes smoothly both ways, from initial to desired and backwards. You only need to `rotate` when `checked`:

```css
#menu-toggle ~ label i {
  transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
}

#menu-toggle:checked ~ label i {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
<label>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</label>
```